# Get rectangles from the Canvas

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am working on a windows phone project. I would like to use a function for my collision.

this is the code I use:

```
foreach (Rectangle mrec in mCanvas.Children) 
{
    if (my_ellipse.Margin.Top + my_ellipse.Height > mrec.Margin.Top && my_ellipse.Margin.Top <= mrec.Margin.Top + mrec.Height && my_ellipse.Margin.Left + my_ellipse.Width >= mrec.Margin.Left && my_ellipse.Margin.Left <= mrec.Margin.Left + mrec.Width)
    {
        my_ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }
    else
    {
        my_ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }
}
```

But when I use this, the `foreach` loop does not only grabs the `Rectangle` elements. It also grabs the `TextBlock` and the `Ellipse`.

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: You could use Linq's `OfType`.

Comment: @juharr Why not an answer?

Comment: So your problem exactly is that the color is applied to more elements than you want (rectangles)? Or that objects inside the rectangles are also changed?

Comment: this is the error I get when I run the application: An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App2.ni.EXE but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Ellipse' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Children` contains objects that are not of type `Rectangle` your `foreach` is attempting to cast each item in `Children` to `Rectangle`.  Instead you need to test if each item is a `Rectangle` first.

```
foreach (var child in mCanvas.Children) 
{
    Rectangle mrec = child as Rectangle;
    if(mrec != null)
    {
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) to do the filtering.

```
foreach (Rectangle mrec in mCanvas.Children.OfType<Rectangle>()) 
{
    // Your logic here
}
```